# Why the output of this getchar and getch is different when printed in int?

Tags: c

I use DevCpp, just curious and want to know why this 2 is different,

```
char ch_1=getchar ();
printf ("getchar: %d\n", ch_1);
char ch_2=getch ();
printf ("getch: %d\n", ch_2);
```

I pressed "Enter" 2 times

```
getchar: 10
getch: 13
```

It produced 10 and 13, which means `getchar` produces 10 (ascii of `\n`) and `getch` produces 13 (ascii of `\r`). Why is it different? Why not both 10 or both 13? Why `getch` produces **carriage return** while `getchar` produces **new line**?

Comment: try to press "enter" only one time

Comment: @IłyaBursov It will wait for an input for getch...

Comment: @usr2564301 You mean `getch` first and then `getchar`? It prints out 13 and 10.

Comment: `getch` is a non-standard Microsoft function that bypasses buffering.  Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @TomKarzes What do you mean by **bypasses buffering**? My English is not that good so I don't understand well...

Comment: [off-topic] best way to learn C is to ignore Microsoft.

Comment: @LastSecond959 The C standard I/O library supports input and output buffering.  This means that data is saved in a buffer and only sent when the buffer is full, or when it needs to be sent.  In contrast, unbuffered I/O always occurs immediately, and in general is much less efficient because it can make far more system calls.  You want to avoid unbuffered I/O as much as possible.  And you also want to avoid mixing buffered and unbuffered I/O for a given stream.